# How do I change the Tab Position in a TWebPageControl component?

Tags: delphi, tabs, tms, tms-web-core, tpagecontrol

I've added a `TWebPageControl` component to my form with three tabs, but the tabs are aligned to the top:

[image: TMS Web Project in Browser with TWebPageControl]

Is there a way to align the tabs to the bottom or left side instead of the top?

---

I want to achieve something similar to the `TabPosition` property on the `TTabControl` component from FireMonkey:

[image: TabPosition in TabControl in Delphi FireMonkey]

If I set `TabPosition` to `Bottom` in `TTabControl`:

[image: Delphi - TabPosition to Bottom in TTabControl]

How can I do this or something similar in TMS WEB Core with the `TWebPageControl` in order to position the tabs on the bottom instead of the top?

Comment: Instead of post 15 questions per days, if you bought the TMS component, you have a doc that explain you how use it. You have access to a dedicated forum for the TMS component

Comment: @Bosshoss You can only post up to a maximum of 5 or 6 questions per day. Also the docs are available to trial users as well. I did have a look at the docs, but I didn't see anything in terms of changing the position of the tabs. So that's why I'm posting the question.

Comment: But why not asking support right away?

Comment: @AmigoJack Like sending an email to TMS? Because the TMS Support Center website is only for licensed users.

Comment: Don't mistake Stack Overflow as an alternative for potential missing support/documentation for one single product you don't want to pay for. People here pay with their free time and effort, too.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes. I know. I'm spending a lot of time figuring out questions on StackOverflow and posting answers to help others in the future. This exact question we're currently on, I've been spending the last 5 hours trying to find a solution and write an answer. Also, it's not that I don't want to pay for it. I think the product is great. I'll most likely end up buying it soon when I start working on actual projects. In the meantime, I'm using the trial and just learning how it works and seeing if it's a viable product or not. That is the point of a trial after all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This took forever to figure out. I could not find a property or method to change the position of the tabs. So I had to write my own function to change the position. It's not perfect, but it's kind of working.

Here's a function that changes the Tabs' position to the bottom:

```
procedure ChangePageControlTabsToBottom(aPageControl: TWebPageControl);
var
  jsPageControl: TJSHTMLElement;
  jsPageControlTabs: TJSNode;
begin
  jsPageControl := aPageControl.ElementHandle;
  jsPageControlTabs := jsPageControl.getElementsByTagName('ul').item(0);
  asm
    jsPageControlTabs.style['position'] = 'absolute';
    jsPageControlTabs.style['bottom'] = '0';
  end;
  aPageControl.ActivePage.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('top', '0');
end;
```

All you do is pass your `TWebPageControl` component into the procedure as a parameter and then it will align your tabs to the bottom:

[image: TMS Web Project with a TWebPageControl component and bottom tabs]

And here's a function to change the tabs to be left aligned:

```
procedure ChangePageControlTabsToLeft(aPageControl: TWebPageControl);
var
  jsPageControl: TJSHTMLElement;
  jsPageControlTabs: TJSNode;
  jsPageControlTabLinks: TJSNode;
  ulWidth: String;
begin
  jsPageControl := aPageControl.ElementHandle;
  jsPageControlTabs := jsPageControl.getElementsByTagName('ul').item(0);
  asm
    jsPageControlTabLinks = jsPageControl.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (let i = 0; i < jsPageControlTabLinks.length; i++)
        jsPageControlTabLinks[i].style['min-width'] = '0';
    jsPageControlTabs.style['writing-mode'] = 'vertical-lr';
    ulWidth = jsPageControlTabs.getBoundingClientRect().right + 'px';
  end;
  aPageControl.ActivePage.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('top', '0');
  aPageControl.ActivePage.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('left', ulWidth);
end;
```

[image: TMS Web Project with a TWebPageControl component and left tabs]

The issue with the `TWebPageControl` component though is that it keeps changing the properties every time you switch to a new tab or if the form resizes. So you need to call `ChangePageControlTabsToBottom(WebPageControl);` in these events also:

- Form's `onCreate` event
- Form's `onShow` event
- Form's `onResize` event
- Every TabSheet's `onShow` event

Comment: Rearranging HTML elements by CSS is rather trivial. Now do that for "_left side_" like it was in your question, too.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes. I'm busy with the left side. Will post once finished 

Comment: When you come back in February you should have it working by then - I expect an updated answer.

Comment: @AmigoJack Hey. I'm back. I actually had the left aligned already working in October, but I didn't get a chance to update my answer yet. I just updated my answer with the function to align the tabs to bottom and left. Once I get some more time on my hands, then I will try to make a better function where you can pass in a param to choose left, bottom, right or top for the tabs. That would be nice.